# Devise Angular Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am trying to authenticate into devise via angular. On loading localhost, I see a POST 401 error. This issue seems to be with some devise setting, as my X-CSRF-TOKEN *is* being passed, but my POST requests aren't accepted.

I am able to register a user successfully, and immediately log in to that user (register also logs user in). I am then able to log out.

Here is the issue: I cannot log in to that user again.

My angular app is inside rails, so the two aren't disconnected.

What do I do? Here are relevant files:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['templates','ui.router','ui.bootstrap', 'Devise']); 
myApp.config([
'$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
return $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  }
  ]);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider)      {

/**
 * Routes and States
 */
 $stateProvider
 .state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
 .state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
  onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', function($state, Auth) {
    Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
      $state.go('home');
    })
  }]
})
 .state('register', {
  url: '/register',
  templateUrl: 'register.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
  onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', function($state, Auth) {
    Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
      $state.go('home');
    })
  }]
});

// default fall back route
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

// enable HTML5 Mode for SEO
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

myApp.run(function() {
  return console.log('angular app running');
});
```

**authCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('AuthCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$state',
'Auth',
function($scope, $state, Auth){

    $scope.login = function() {
        Auth.login($scope.user).then(function(){
            $state.go('home');
        });
    };

    $scope.register = function() {
        Auth.register($scope.user).then(function(){
            $state.go('home');
        });
    };
}]);
```

**navCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('NavCtrl', [
'$scope',
'Auth',
function($scope, Auth){

    $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;
    $scope.logout = Auth.logout;

    Auth.currentUser().then(function (user){
        $scope.user = user;
    });

    $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function (e, user){
        $scope.user = user;
    });

    $scope.$on('devise:login', function (e, user){
        $scope.user = user;
    });

    $scope.$on('devise:logout', function (e, user){
        $scope.user = {};
    });
}]);
```

**applicaton_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

respond_to :json

def index
end
end
```

I have Devise gem installed, and using angular, angular-ui, angular-devise in Bowerfile

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing :exception to :null_session worked.. Why is this?